# using multiple curls inside for loop in C

Tags: c, libcurl

I am a beginner in both C programming and libcurl and writing a program to fetch 1000 data values from a website. The website provides a job number and is redirected into another page for the results. Since, the code I have written is almost 500 lines, I am giving a general flow of the program and a short code which I think is the problematic area:

```
  for(row=0;row<1000;row++)
  {
   ------ 
    url = "http://example.com";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curlHandle = curl_easy_init(); 
if(curlHandle)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrStr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, dl_lowspeed_bytes);    
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, dl_lowspeed_time);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    free(url);
    curlErr = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);    
    if(curlErr != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(curlErr));
    }
    else 
    {
        curlErr = curl_easy_getinfo(curlHandle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url_new);
        if((CURLE_OK == curlErr) && url_new)
        {
            sprintf(job,"%.*s\n", 18, url_new + 28);
            if((ptr1 = strchr(job, '\n')) != NULL)
                *ptr1 = '\0';
            init_string(&s);
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800 );
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url_new);
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
            curlErr1 = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
            printf("###### %lu\t%s\n",strlen(s.ptr),s.ptr);
            free(s.ptr);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
    }
}
```

The functions are:

```
  struct string
  {
   char *ptr;
   size_t len;
  };

  void init_string(struct string *a)
  {
   a->len = 0;
   a->ptr = malloc(a->len+1);
   if (a->ptr == NULL)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   a->ptr[0] = '\0';
  }

  size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *a)
  {
   size_t new_len = a->len + size*nmemb;
   a->ptr = realloc(a->ptr, new_len+1);
   if (a->ptr == NULL)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   memcpy(a->ptr+a->len, ptr, size*nmemb);
   a->ptr[new_len] = '\0';
   a->len = new_len;
   return size*nmemb;
  }
```

The program shows no error of any kind. But out of the 1000 data, almost 50% couldn't be fetched due to curl_easy_perform() failed: Timeout was reached; and 20% of them have the output of the line strlen(s.ptr),s.ptr => 0. The rest are fetched correctly.

The verbose option for the zero output gave the following:

- Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
- getaddrinfo(3) failed for :80
- Couldn't resolve host ''
- Closing connection #1
- Couldn't resolve host name
  0

Please suggest the possible errors in the program.

Comment: I haven't read the entire code but I see you initialise curl inside the for loop: You don't have to do that as it will only make your code slower, and will probably even lead to weird runtime errors. Instead move curl_setopt and curl_init outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is how I would fetch data using cURL


static CURL *curl = NULL;

CURL *initCURL(void)
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)  
    { 
        // now set all the desired options
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        // etc
    }
    else
    { // else cURL object creation failed
      // display appropriate error message
    } 
}

void endCurl(void)
{
    // and then when all done with the cURL object,
    // cleanup
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}


CURLcode execCurl( CURL *curl )
{  
    CURLcode res;
    // Perform this request, for each fetch

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    // Check for errors
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    return( res );
}


Note:
I have had this same problem with the cURL timeout occurring.
The best recovery method I found is:
when a timeout occurs, retry the communication, requesting the same data
```